# How to configure MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1 in gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mpandroidchart

In my android application i have to create charts, so I likes to use MPAndroidCharts for that.I saw the latest release on that is v3.0.1 but i can configure it on gradle correctly.I got below error when i use its gradle configuration.

```
        Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
    > Could not find com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1.
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.jar
            file:/usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.pom
            file:/usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.jar
            file:/usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.pom
            file:/usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.jar
```

What I am doing wrong?? Below is my gradle configuration.

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myproject"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
        compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
        compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.1.RELEASE') {
            exclude module: 'spring-core'
        }
        compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    }
```

Comment: You are probably missing the repository where gradle can look for the lib:

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}`

Comment: @RomanKolomenskii I am planning to create an offline app.Does this create any problem if there is no internet access??

Comment: No, it only downloads it (the jar file) once when you sync your project

Comment: @RomanKolomenskii Where should i place this lines?? Is it inside android { } or outside ??

Comment: At root level of your build.gradle, but not app/build.gradle.

Comment: @RomanKolomenskii  I got this warning after that.... Unindexed remote maven repositories found. Disable...
 The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet: https://jitpack.io...What to do??

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add that in your build.gradle (Project:...):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it inside android { } or outside

Comment: It's in the other build.gradle, the project one not the app one. The part with `allprojects` should already be there